# Add comment length counter on the mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, mobile-web

I know that comments have to be at least 15 chars for the system to post it. I noticed that on the mobile site, there is no "x chars to go..." warning.

If I try to post a comment that is too short, it silently fails and still no mention of minimum length at all.

Can the length counter that is present in the full site theme be added to the mobile theme please?

Comment: Not only are comments second-class citizens on SO, the mobile site is also a second-class citizen. As annoying as that can be, I'm expecting a [tag:status-deferred] here.

Comment: It took me quite a long time (and several browser restarts) to figure out what the problem was here (I was posting a too long comment so it was even less obvious why it was failing)

Comment: Yes, can we please fix this? The most annoying part is that the user is left to guess why the comment they're adding is not getting accepted - no error message, the Add Comment button just doesn't do anything. Finally get it to submit, and click edit, and now I'm allowed to know how many characters I have left? I add a lot more comments than I edit - the mobile version has enough limitations, let's please clean this one up.

Comment: For the love of god please implement this, so we don't have to copy the comment, switch to desktop site, and paste it to check what happened when the "submit" button silently fails. Doesn't help that in 2015 the Android and chrome devs still haven't figured out a way to make select all -> copy -> paste sane for people with normal sized fingers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was never an intentional omission, the JavaScript will be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: It still does not show anything for comments that are too long.

Demo: https://keybase.pub/1of1/videos/B576A976-D34C-4D0D-AD91-9F0733ECBA20.mov

Answer (score 10):

The interesting thing is that the [code for comment character count is already there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131252/comment-charcount-on-mobile), just that it is only invoked when you *edit* a comment. So code bloat is not a problem here.

I don't see any reason why the feature can't be triggered on creating a comment.