# How do I delete or flag comments using the mobile website?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, mobile-web

While browsing the site on my Android mobile, I found that there is no option to delete comments through the mobile website.

In order to take screenshots, I recreated the issue using the mobile link found in the website footer section and rendered the mobile layout in Google Chrome browser on my desktop machine.

**Here are the steps that I performed:**

1. On the site footer section, clicked on the link *mobile*. Refer screenshot **#1**.
2. I navigated to one of my questions and typed in a test comment. Clicked the Add comment button to submit the comment. Refer screenshot **#2**. I didn't get any error message when the comment was less than the required minimum number of characters. This minimum error not appearing issue has already been reported through this post: [Add comment length counter on the mobile site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100053/minimum-comment-length-is-hidden-on-the-mobile-site)
3. I see the comment on the mobile application but there is no delete option. Refer screenshot **#3**.
4. On the mobile application's footer section, clicked on the full site link to switch to the standard website layout.
5. On the standard layout, I deleted the comment that I posted using the mobile layout using the delete button.

Is this by design that the comments cannot be deleted / flagged on the mobile website or is it a bug?

Screenshot **#6** was added in response to comments from @M. Tibbits that flagging is not allowed on mobile. It seems flagging is allowed on questions but I didn't see any option for flagging comments.

**Screenshots:**

**#1:** mobile link at the site footer section

[image: Mobile link]

**#2:** Add comment

[image: Add comment]

**#3:** Comment added but no delete option

[image: Comment added but no delete option]

**#4:** Switch to full site

[image: Switch to full site]

**#5:** Delete option on the full site

[image: Delete option on the full site]

**#6:** Flagging on mobile

[image: Flagging on mobile]

Comment: I've also found the mobile website is a bit too pared down in some cases.  For instance, I don't think you can flag anything from the mobile website.  That said, I think it was optimized for question/answer *viewing* not for moderation, etc.

Comment: @M. Tibbits: I think that one reason could be due to the size of the icon that might cause problem but I feel a link can be provided instead. The icon is already very small on the normal desktop. However, it looks like you can upvote a comment. :-) May be good things are allowed on the mobile but not the bad ones (like flagging, deleting.) :-)

Comment: +1 Siva.  It might also increase the noise in upvoting though.

Comment: @m.t you can flag from mobile as of a week ago; try it

Comment: @Jeff,  Yep I see it now. Awesome! Though I guess Siva's right, you can't flag or delete comments through the mobile interface.

Comment: I'm placing a bounty on this; you can't delete comments through the mobile interface still.  I'm curious as to why this isn't a feature implemented already (it implies the mobile site and the main site are two separate sites, when they *should* be as similar as technologically possible).

Comment: I found this a problem today as well. I wanted to delete a comment and could not, until I pulled out my tablet.

Answer (score 1):

You can now delete comments on the mobile theme - flagging is still unsupported.

Comment: Why not allow mobile comment flagging?

Comment: How's this [status-completed] when mobile flagging is still unsupported?