# Allow flagging comments on mobile site

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, comment-flags

While using the mobile site on my Android phone, I saw a comment that I wanted to flag but there was no flag button. After searching, I saw [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100706/how-do-i-delete-or-flag-comments-using-the-mobile-website/172432#172432) that says flagging comments is not supported on mobile site.

Could the ability to flag comments be added to the mobile site?

Comment: You can of course go to desktop mode (using link at the bottom) if you need to, but I agree this is a poor solution

Comment: As a moderator who uses the mobile UI a lot, this lack has been a thorn in my side.

Comment: @RichardTingle I tried using it but didn't show the flag. It only showed the upvote button.

Comment: @Unitato please do NOT make useless edits just to bump. Especially when it is wrong grammar. Thanks. If you want to bump and have no valid edit, start a bounty!

Comment: Apologies @ShaWizDowArd. I'll not do this next time.

Comment: Flagging is supported now.

Comment: @hat I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @fred: you have to choose the full site by clicking the "full site" link at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 12):

It seems that all that's missing from the mobile view is the actual flag link: if you use developer tools to inject an `<a class="comment-flag">` element somewhere inside the comment row and click it, a seemingly functional flag dialog pops up.  (I haven't actually tried to submit an actual flag that way, but I see no obvious reason why it shouldn't work.)

Thus, it shouldn't be hard to write a user script to do this — the only problem is the lack of user script support in mobile browsers ([Tampermonkey browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.biniok.tampermonkey) notwithstanding).

(In fact, the reason I noticed this is that the code [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) uses to work around [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-upvoting-it) is currently (v1.8.0) missing an `isMobile` check, and so ends up injecting (somewhat ugly) flag links into the mobile view for any comments that you've upvoted.  I'll need to fix that, but I thought this would be an interesting observation to mention, even if it's not as practically useful as it might be if more mobile browsers supported user scripts.)

---

Update: Now that Firefox for Android can run the [SOUP extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/so-unofficial-patch-soup/) (as well as other user scripts via [Violentmonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/violentmonkey/)), using a user script to modify the SE interface on mobile devices has become a lot more practical.  Accordingly, as of version 1.50, SOUP contains [a fix for this issue](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/68cdb600b9a0e4901790585259216567ed548e33/SOUP.user.js#L1558). Here's what the UI looks like (as of SOUP v1.52):

[image: Screenshot of mobile comment flag dialog]

(Ps. After casting that test flag, I discovered a minor cosmetic bug: the fancy SVG flag icon [turns into the word "flag"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEUnq.png) once the dialog has been submitted. I'll fix that in the next release.)