# Vote on comments in iOS app and mobile app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

This is the first time I add a question using the iOS app, so a good test.

I had like to suggest a feature that applies to both the iOS app and the mobile version of the website:

Can we allow to vote on comments? This is not possible yet.

Comment: In the mobile version we can vote comments up, there's a big arrow next to each comment (make sure you're logged in). If you don't have it submit a bug report. As for iOS app, good idea! :)

Comment: This feature will be implemented pretty soon.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky just curious, what is holding it back? We can already flag so why not vote up? API limitation?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Basically, just coding the UI, which I am literally doing right now.

Comment: @BrianNickel cool, good luck with that! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: you are right. My bad. It doesn't allow flagging comments.

Comment: @PatrickHofman right, and it's [already requested to have it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213709/152859). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be in the next build.  We also squashed an API bug so we've go "Remove up vote."