# Error: the question could not be loaded

Tags: bug, ios-app

When I was trying to open [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226211/vote-on-comments-in-ios-app-and-mobile-app) I just added using the iOS app I received this error:

> Error The question could not be loaded

Reproduction scenario:

- add a question;
- in my case it didn't open it directly;
- it doesn't show up in the list yet;
- I opened my profile and clicked the question;
- bang!

[The problem still seems to exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255821/cant-find-question-immediately-after-posting)

Comment: I'm taking a look at this...

Comment: Could you provide some more context on how you opened the question? Were you navigating through the question listing, or did this occur immediately after you submitted the question (And the app tried to display it)?

Comment: After several tries, I am unable to reproduce this issue. It is possible that you won't be able to load a question from another part of the for a few seconds after you submit it (some time is required for correct propagation). However, the app should always open the question directly after it's successfully submitted. Does the app never open the question for you after submitting?

Comment: @Arie: the second one it did. The first it didn't. I experience some timeouts in the app, also with closing a question.  Can that be the cause? Btw, I tried opening it several times.

Comment: timeouts might be related. Are you on a non-wifi connection (like 3G) or a connection that might have a lot of dropped packets?

Comment: @Arie: no. Very stable wifi. I could open other parts of the app instantly.

Comment: I can't easily track down the source of the issue. Our crash logger wasn't working for a while, and unfortunately your bug happened during that time. If you can reproduce it, we should be able to catch it though.

Comment: Otherwise, if you can't reproduce it, feel free to vote it to close.

Comment: When you say "bang", do you mean you get the above error message or that the app crashes?

Comment: I think I have some clues as to how this is happening. I'll be taking a look in the next few days. Thanks for keeping up with it ;)

Comment: Hi @PatrcikHofman, could you try this again on 0.1.50? We've had some changes to bulletproof networking recently, and I believe one of them fixed this issue.

Comment: @Arie [not fixed yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255821/cant-find-question-immediately-after-posting).

Comment: Still happening see my question (which at time of posting I didn't know was a duplicate of this one) - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/255821/289598