# Can't find question immediately after posting

Tags: bug, questions, ios-app

Just posted a question here via iOS app - immediately I get an error that the question can't be found, it has been posted but I can't view - it the screenshot shows the error, with the post title behind it:

[image]

Comment: The text has changed. The error is the same though. Too bad this isn't fixed yet...

Comment: I guess it's some kind of race condition, when the server is bt busy and it takes few seconds for the question to actually be  pushed to database, and the app doesn't know it.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how the website differs from the mobile app in handling adding questions. It seems there is something happening here...

Comment: I'll raise one on the website and see what happens, certainly never seen it with questions raised on the site in the past

Comment: No indeed. That was the reason I said so. This should be analyzed by the devs.

Comment: Happened again when raising the following question when the app tries to display the question when you've hit Submit - http://stackoverflow.com/q/30675530/1868534