# Comments that exceed the maximum length fail silently on Mobile

Tags: support, comments, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minimum comment length is hidden on the mobile site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100053/minimum-comment-length-is-hidden-on-the-mobile-site)

When using the mobile site, attempting to enter a comment that exceeds the maximum character limit results in a failure with no message indicating what the source of the failure is.

Is there any way to give some sort of user feedback that the maximum number of characters is being exceeded?

Comment: Minimum comment length is presumably a separate check from maximum comment length.

Comment: The point is the same.  There is no indication at all of the proper comment size on mobile.

Comment: The point is the same, but the solution to your question could possibly not solve the problem in mine. Either they are two separate questions, or yours should perhaps be reworded to cover the entire issue, instead of just the "minimum" side of it?

Comment: Well that's true, the SE devs [do have a habit of overlooking little things...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116522/eeeek-what-the-fruit-is-going-on-with-all-these-theme-changes) :P  I guess we can leave this question open.  Too bad I can't take back my vote.

Comment: This is why I always try to make sure my specs detail each issue, instead of relying on "obvious" conclusions :)