# Comment charcount on mobile

Tags: feature-request, comments, mobile-web, character-limit

I recently noticed that the mobile site supports  'x characters left' in comments. But, it's not always there. Some investigation revealed that it shows up while *editing* a comment but not while posting it.

This seems illogical... Comment posting is more frequent than comment editing, and this is more useful when writing a comment.

Extending this feature won't add bloat; the code is already there.

Could  the character count functionality be extended to all comment boxes?

Comment: This is really a problem... I was trying to send a comment earlier from my cellphone and was like !*&?$!*& why is it not working.. And then when I got on my pc and tried to send the exact same comment I saw the "enter at least X character more"..