# Tell me how many characters I've got left for comments in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, android-app

When typing a comment on the Android app, it doesn't tell me how many characters I have to type, or how many I have left. It would be nice if it displayed it as I was typing (like on the website), perhaps in the middle gap at the top.

Comment: Well, it's not showing even in the mobile theme of the site.

Comment: I don't really use that. Sounds like another [meta-tag:feature-request] though!

Comment: Actually it was reported long ago [as a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100053/152859), never to receive much attention.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No, that a bug for the mobile site. This issue is about the android app, currently in closed alpha testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently being displayed. This is implemented.